# Open-source Django model for Twitter

Tags: django, api, twitter, django-models

Where can I find a Django model for Twitter for caching tweets?  I want to be able to capture tweets, users, etc and the relationships between them.  I'd like not to have to update this things myself whenever the Twitter API changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/) is a very good open-sourced library just for this purpose and works great in Django

Comment: I plan on using Tweepy, but with this question, I'm specifically looking for a Django model to store tweets after I have retrieved them using Tweepy.

Comment: @bmasc same did u find a solution?